# User "read" command while executing remote scripts over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

Let me explain my situation first.
I have an alias in .bashrc:

```
doscript () { ssh root@server$1 -p2202 "bash -s" < ~/scripts/$2 $3; }
```

I have a script, that basically consists of several actions like:

```
check current settings
read comment
do actions
write $comment in a file
restart service
```

So I run a command

```
doscript server scriptname parameter
```

However the "read comment" part does not work. Instead of waiting until I enter the comment, it immediately gets executes, adding nothing to the comment file.

Is there a way to enter variable in that case?

Comment: when you are launching a non-interactive session, there is no tty assigned to that process. Hence there is no place to `read` the input from. what you can do is to `ssh server "echo \"this is my comment\" > /tmp/commentfile"` before you execute your actual script and chage your script to read the comment from the `/tmp/commentfile` instead of from the `tty`.

Comment: oh, that explains everything. Well, the thing is, I need to view the settings first before I enter the commend as it depends on what I see. I guess I'll need to split the "checksettings" part into a separate script.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this without changing too much is to copy the file
to the remote and then execute it, hence keeping stdin available
for your tty input. Eg

```
scp -P 2202 ~/scripts/$2 root@server$1:./myscript
ssh -t root@server$1 -p2202 bash ./myscript $3
```

or if you cannot `scp` replace that line by

```
ssh root@server$1 -p2202 'cat >./myscript' <~/scripts/$2
```

Comment: Copying the script into some temporary folder might be the solution, thank you!

Comment: The key is to add `-t`, +1 for this one